# Is it possible to override GetValue() method for complex types?

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

I have a `Job` class as below:

```
public class Job
{
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public SalaryRange SalaryRange { get; set; }
}

public class SalaryRange
{
    public decimal MinSalary { get; set; }
    public decimal MaxSalary { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to calculate the checksum of job `object`. The purpose of this checksum is to indicate if any property of job has been modified... so I want to build a string which contains all of its property values and get the checksum of this string:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Calculate_job_checksum()
{
    var salary = new SalaryRange()
    {
        MinSalary = 15,
        MaxSalary = 20
    };
    
    vat job = new Job()
    {
        JobTitle= "Civil Engineer",
        SalaryRange = salary
    };
    
    string stringifiedValues = "";
    PropertyInfo[] properties = job.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
    {
        if (p.CanRead))
        {
            // combine all values
            var val = p.GetValue(job);
            stringifiedValues += val.ToString();
        }
    }

    // get the checksum
    jobChecksum = stringifiedValues.GetChecksum();
}
```

The problem is `GetValue()` does not get the value of the complex type (i.e. `SalaryRange`) correctly, it returns the namespace of the class, i.e. the value of `stringifiedValues` is:

```
"Civil EngineerMySolutionName.ProjectName.FolderName"
```

Is it possible to override or change the behavior of `GetValue()` to return stringified values of nested properties?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Side note: the order returned from `GetProperties()` is officially undefined - you should *not* rely on order being reliable; you might also want to add the *names* ... to be honest, it might be easier to just use a JSON serializer or something to stringify the object model!

Comment: "The purpose of this checksum is to indicate if any property of job has been modified" - be sure you're using the right tools here. Checksums or hashes are usually smaller than their input range and so can answer the question "definitely different" but not answer the question "exactly the same"

Comment: The easiest way is to serialize your object and hash it. Maybe as JSON. This is 2 lines of code and works with (almost) every object.
But if you just want to compare 2 objects and already have c#9 then records could be what you want.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It depends on what hashing algorithm you are using. If you take a common one than a bitflip in your memory is much more likely than a hash collision. So for practical use cases you can say "exactly the same"

Comment: @MarcGravell: thanks for pointing out that the order of `GetProperties()` is undefined, which make a whole lot of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fetching the value just fine; the *problem* is that the value is a `SalaryRange` instance, and the default `object.ToString()` implementation is to write the type name. You could just override that:

```cs
public class SalaryRange
{
    public decimal MinSalary { get; set; }
    public decimal MaxSalary { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{MinSalary}-{MaxSalary}"; // for example
}
```